# Constructing set of functions that give a good basis after a certain integral

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functions

I need a set of functions that can be used as a basis *after a specific integration*. In other words: I integrate a set of functions enumerated by a parameter $k$ where the integral depends on another parameter $L$. I then need to approximate a set of numbers $\eta_L$ depending on $L$ as closely as possible using superpositions of the integration results - where an exact solution should be possible if the matrix of integrals organized by $k,L$ is invertible. Is there a strategy that can be used to find such a set of functions?

More specifically this is the situation:

I start out with functions $f_k^S(u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2)$ of four complex "spinor" variables $u_1,v_1,u_2$ and $v_2$. These are coordinates for two particles on a sphere of radius 1, and given in terms of regular spherical variables as

$(u,v)=(\cos(\theta/2)\exp(i\phi/2),\sin(\theta/2)\exp(-i\phi/2))$

with $\theta\in\{0,\pi\}$ and $\phi\in\{0,2\pi\}$. The parameters $k$ and $2S$ are integers so that $2S\in\{0,\ldots\}$ and $0\leq k\leq M\leq 2S$; and $M$ denotes the number of functions (plus one).

The functions $f_k^S$ are in fact only functions of the chord distance between the two particles $r=|u_1v_2-u_2v_1|$. But I still need to keep in mind the above because the mentioned integral is as follows:

$
g_k(L)=\int_0^{\pi}d\theta_1d\theta_2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_1d\phi_2|u_1v_2-u_2v_1|^{4S-2L}|u_1|^{2L}|u_2|^{2L}\ f^S_k(u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2)
$

where $L$ is another integer $L\in\{0,\ldots,M\}$. Note that $f_k^S$ are not functions of $L$ but potentially of $S$. Then comes the "basis" part: I now need to approximate $M+1$ numbers $\eta_L$ as closely as possible using superpositions of $g_k$:

$
\eta_0=c_0g_0(0)+c_1g_1(0)+\ldots+c_{M}g_M(0) \\
\eta_1=c_0g_0(1)+c_1g_1(1)+\ldots+c_{M}g_M(1) \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots \\
\eta_{M}=c_0g_0(M)+c_1g_1(M)+\ldots+c_Mg_M(M)\ ,
$

with coefficients $c_k$. The numbers $\eta_L$ are given as a complicated function of $S$ and $L$; here is a log plot of the first 21 (i.e. $L=0,\ldots,20$) for $2S=41$:

[image: pp]

As you can see they decay rapidly, which probably makes it harder.

So again the question is: How can I choose $f^S_k$ to be able to approximate $\eta_L$ as good as possible for a given $S$? Ideally it should be possible to do it exactly (i.e. getting $M+1$ of the $\eta_L$ exactly).

As an example: The best results I've gotten is by choosing the following functions:

$f^S_k=\frac{\big(2r\sqrt{S}\big)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}\Big(1+2r^2\frac{S+1}{5}\Big)^{-S}\ ,$

where again $r=|u_1v_2-u_2v_1|$. The above integral can then be solved using the substitution

$u_2=u_1u'_2-v_1^*v_2'$

$v_2=v_1u'_2+u_1^*v_2'\ ,$

and the identity

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi_2'|a-be^{-i\phi_2'}|^{2L}=2\pi\sum_{j=0}^L{L \choose j}^2a^{2j}b^{2L-2j}\ ,$

which for the above $f^S_k$ gives

$\displaystyle g_k(L)=\frac{16\pi^2}{\sqrt{k!}}\sqrt{S}^k\sum_{j=0}^L{L \choose j}^2\frac{(L+j)!(L-j)!j!\Gamma(2S+k/2+1-j)}{(2L+1)!\Gamma(2S+k/2+2)} $

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  _2F_1(S,2S+k/2-j+1;2S+k/2+2;-\frac{S+1}{2\lambda})\ ,$

where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function. This gives good results for low $S$, but breaks down when $S$ gets too big. One symptom of this can be seen by looking at the rank of the matrix $g_k(L)$ with indices $k$ and $L$, which has maximal rank up until higher values of $S$.

I realize this is a long winded and kind of ugly question but I'm really stuck, and hoping there are some general strategies in this kind of situation. Any ideas?